# Exclusives Reservation Granule (ERG) on Apple's processors

Tags: ios, assembly, arm, processor

Does anyone know what is ERG on Apple's A5, A5X, A6 and A6X processors?

We ran into an obscure bug with LDREX/STREX instructions and the behavior is different between A5's and A6's. The only explanation I have is that they have different ERG, but can't find anything on that. I also could not find a way to retrieve this value, the MRC instruction seems to be prohibited in the user mode on iOS.

Thank you!

Comment: While a correct question, I am somewhat intrigued as to why you need to know for the purpose of debugging? The size of the ERG should have nothing other than performance impacts.
Could you explain what the behaviour you are seeing is, and what you were expecting to see instead?

Comment: We encountered a bug when compiler generated a code that hit ERG when reading an exclusively accessed variable - thus entering an endless loop as STREX always failed. This failure happened only on A6X devices.

Comment: Ok. But without seeing the affected code, I am unable to comment on whether you have may be an actual hardware bug, or whether what you have is a (subtle) software bug that you can work around by carefully aligning your locks, but may pop back up again on other processors. The ERG _does_not_ affect architecturally correct software on architecturally correct hardware in any other ways than performance.

Answer (score 2):

On OMAP 4460 (ARM Cortex-A9, same as Apple A5/A5X) ERG is 32 bytes (which is same as cache line size).

I don't know that those values are on A6/A6X (and there is no way to find out without loading your own driver, which you can not do on Apple devices), but my guestimate is that cache line size increased to 64 bytes, and so did ERG.

Alternatively, you may optimize the algorithm for the architectural maximum of 512 words (2K bytes).

Comment: Our testing shows that it is 64 bytes, too. The strange thing is that for A5 the test always works as if it works without ERG at all.

Answer (score -1):

ERG size is a *critical* consideration when using ldrex/strex.

When an ldrex has been issued, if a memory access occurs in the ERG within which the ldrex read occured, the strex will fail.

It is not unusual to have a structure which contains an ldrex/strex target and some additional data, where the additional data is accessed between the ldrex/strex pair (for example, to store the value loaded by ldex).

If the ldrex/strex target has insufficient padding in the structure (i.e. the ERG size chosen is too small) the access to other members of the structure will therefore cause the strex to ALWAYS fail.

Game over, lights out.

Regarding ldrex/strex, ARM implements a "local monitor" and a "global monitor".  On systems with only a local monitor, the only way an ldrex/strex can fail is if two ldrexs are issued on the same address prior to an strex having been issued - only systems with global monitors actually notice memory bus traffic within the ERG of the ldrex/strex target.

ARM systems vary hugely and I suspect there are systems which have only local monitors and so do not in fact actually support ldrex/strex.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.